# Caliburn.micro show busy indicator when loading controls

Tags: caliburn.micro, busyindicator

I am looking for a way to show a busy indicator when Caliburn is loading a control. That means when caliburn automatically calls the OnInitialize-Method I would like it to show an busy indicator above the control that it loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this by using coroutines. Search documentation on caliburn's project home, there's a 'ShowScreen' class that implements IResult.

Comment: I suspect that you also answered http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/356669#post839645 so I will accept this.